# Execute Javascript if element with specific CSS class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that displays an error div with a class of '`validation-errors`' if the user enters an incorrect value into a textbox.

Is there a way to execute a javascript function (it adds a CSS property to a button) when the error div is displayed? The function is currently called in `window.onload`.

Is there a way to execute the javascript function if window has changed / element added?

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery to do this?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how I would do that. It's an MVC website, and I don't actually know/understand how the validation message is being displayed - if I did, I could add a call to the function to apply the CSS to the button when the error div/message is displayed. The button basically needs to be updated when this error message is displayed.

Comment: Here's a basic introduction to JQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works. It's basically a JavaScript library that allows you to, among other things, select elements based on the class, id, etc. and trigger events.

Comment: @Liam - Thanks, I can see already it's better than Javascript

Comment: @aspdotnetuser If you just write the CSS-rules in your stylesheet they will apply even to nodes added with AJAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.validation-errors').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  if ($('.validation-errors').length) { 
    // code
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to work - I'm trying to display an alert() to test if it works. I've included it inside <script> tags. I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the div (validation-errors) doesn't exist initially, it's created dynamically, when errors occur. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4):

If you have jQuery on the page:

```
if ($('.validation-errors').length){ /*your code here */ }
```

in pure JS it would be something like this:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("validation-errors").length){ /*your code here */ }
```

Comment: Does the JS code need to be executed for window.onload? If so, how can I make it execute each time the page is updated? i.e the erorrs div is not always displayed.

Comment: @aspdotnetuser Yes, it must be executed after the page is loaded. I wouldn't try to check if the whole page is updated (bad idea), I'd rather find the function that creates these error divs and attach it there.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jQuery, you can do

```
$(".validation-errors").live(function() {/* do whatever you want when your error div exists */ });
```

Comment: That sounds great. I will give that a go and post back later.

Comment: Just remember that "live" function is deprecated in recent releases of jQuery and should be avoided.

Comment: @aspdotnetuser you might want to see tborychowski's comment body my edit in response to that.

Comment: @11684 There is no such event as "live"

Comment: @11684 No :-) There is no such event name as 'live'! jQuery had a function live() to attach events (similar to bind or delegate) but there has never been an event called 'live'. Have a look: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

Comment: Downvoted because of the deprecated function. Please update answer.